# Can't animate subview's frame

Tags: animation, uiimageview, frame, subview

I'm trying to animate a subview's frame but it's not working :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                   animations:^{
                   NSLog(@"BIIIM %@", [_subView subviews]);
                   UIImageView *imageView1 = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:(1)];{
                             imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(76.8 , -100, 33.4, 164);
                             imageView1.alpha = 0.5;   
                                                              }
```

The animation for the alpha is working just fine but the one for the frame is not... Any idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple test as following ,and find it works fine. both the alpha and frame changes.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView1  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    imageView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView1];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
        imageView1.alpha = 0.5;
    }];

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is not so much with the animation because even if I try to change the frame of imageView1 without the animation it doesn't work... But the alpha works. :(

Comment: Hi,I made a simple test as following ,and find it works fine. both the alpha and frame changes.  

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
    UIImageView *imageView1  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    imageView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView1];
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        imageView1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
        imageView1.alpha = 0.5;
    }];

}

Comment: Thanks a lot 流觞_iviedsky! 
I think the problem is more that my superview doesn't let my subview move or something like that. I can't figure out why.